# Can't get react-router-bootstrap Navbar Items to render inline

Tags: react-bootstrap

I have a simple react-bootstrap's `Navbar` tag with several `NavItem` elements inside of each, each of which is nested inside of a react-router-component `LinkContainer` which essentially works the same way as a react-router `NavLink` component. All of the elements are displaying block instead of inline, though, and I'm not sure why.

My Navbar:

```
      <Navbar>
        <Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Brand>
            <a>GeoHunter</a>
          </Navbar.Brand>
        </Navbar.Header>
        <Nav>
          <LinkContainer to="/"><NavItem>Home</NavItem></LinkContainer>
          <LinkContainer to="/users"><NavItem>Users</NavItem></LinkContainer>
          <LinkContainer to="/caches"><NavItem>Caches</NavItem></LinkContainer>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar>
```